# Anyone here with a Sol-20 or images thereof?

Tags: history

I've just completed an obviously long-overdue article on the [Sol-20 for the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol-20).

It really needs some images. Does anyone out there have images **that they took** of this machine? Especially the interior!

Comment: Could you reword this to be more of a question? Perhaps "Are there any images of the Sol-20 licensed under XYZ?"

Comment: Chat would be a better place for this. Or Reddit.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=sol-20+computer

Comment: Nice article. I made a few minor edits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should've asked this in [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked, there's one in the attic. So what kind of pics are needed. And no, I do not own any fancy camera - unless an Apple QuickTake 100 counts :))

[image]

(the black box in the lower right is way more interesting, as it's a rackmount (!) disk drive for an Atari ST.

Comment: What is that CBM machine leaning up there?

Comment: @Wilson It's a V(I)C 20 with/inside a VC1020 expansion chassis. It was quite popular in Europe. Thinking of it, it fits the picture, as it turns the VIC almost into a SOL :)) http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/x1020.html  and https://www.google.com/search?q=CBM+1020&tbm=isch

Comment: Raff, would you be able to take some pictures of this machine with the cover removed? The Sol's expansion chassis was pretty clever (IMHO), and I'm especially interested in showing how that layout worked. The only image I have on the Wiki now is a nice one, but its from the front with the cover on.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Please mail me, so we can close this

Comment: It seems your post with the address was removed. Ping me? It's my first and last name with a period between them on gmail.